# Does ffmpeg support setting the description tag on a per-stream basis?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, mp4

I'm attempting to set a description tag for each of two audio streams within an mp4 file. I'm using a command line similar to this (I've simplified):

```
ffmpeg -i old_movie.mp4 -map 0:0 -c:v copy -map 0:2 -c:a -metadata:s:a:0 description="Narration, Dialogue, Score" -map 0:1 -metadata:s:a:1 description="Director's Commentary"
```

It produces a file, which when I use ffmpeg to check the metadata shows no description tag at all. I've also tried "desc" and "Description", both of which also fail.

What little I can find with Google suggests that "description" is definitely a valid tag for mp4.

Can anyone give me a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

.mkv is fine, but mp4 is not display audio metadeta, and use -metadata:s:a:**0** instead of metadata:s:a:**1**, which is not describe metadeta.

`ffmpeg -i old_movie.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -metadata:s:a:0 description="Narration, Dialogue, Score" -c copy 1.mkv -map 0:1 -metadata:s:a:0 description="Director's Commentary" -c copy 2.mkv`

`ffmpeg -i old_movie.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -metadata:s:a:0 description="Narration, Dialogue, Score" -c copy 1.mp4 -map 0:1 -metadata:s:a:0 description="Director's Commentary" -c copy 2.mp4`